# javascript doesnt work on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this html:

```
   <a style="display:block; padding:100%; text-decoration: none;" href="http://google.com " class="Jasmin" id="target_site_to_visit">

<span data-app-id="88" class="btn" id="visit_site" style="right:22px; top:65px; padding:5px;z-index: -99999;">VISIT SITE</span>

</a>
```

and this jquery:

```
      (function($){
            $('#target_site_to_visit').live('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
           var appName=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('class');
          $.post('db/update_site_viewed.php',{ name:appName }, function(data){

              throw new Error("AppName: "+appName);

          },'html').error(function(data){

             throw new Error("Error: "+data.responseText);
          });
          document.location.href=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('href');
      }); })(jQuery);
```

A problem exists, whenever the button is clicked.. the post method is executed which puts the data into the database. But that only happens when the last line in jquery doesnt exist: document.location.href.. the redirection effects the post somehow..and doesnt probably doesnt give the post method to execute..resulting in no record being inserted to the db (or in other post method doesnt execute).. is it possible that that is the cause..cause the redirection does effect the execution of the post method

Comment: `.live()` will still need and event (`click` probably) btw.

Comment: Yes you forgot the first parameter to ".live()".  Probably you should be using ".on()" now, as ".live()" is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will solve your problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#target_site_to_visit').live("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
       var appName=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('class');
      $.post('db/update_site_viewed.php',{ name:appName }, function(data){

     //    console.log("AppName: "+appName);

      },'html').error(function(data){

       //  console.log("Error: "+data.responseText);
      });
    //  document.location.href=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('href');
  });
```

But use .on() instead of .live().LIke

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("click",'#target_site_to_visit',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
           var appName=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('class');
          $.post('db/update_site_viewed.php',{ name:appName }, function(data){

         //    console.log("AppName: "+appName);

          },'html').error(function(data){

           //  console.log("Error: "+data.responseText);
          });
        //  document.location.href=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('href');
      }); 
   </script>
```

Comment: This is the first time I see someone say *use `.on` instead of `.live`* **AND** get the usage of `.on` correct! +1 :D

Comment: whats teh difference between on and live? why not to use live?

Comment: because there are many reason like .on is too much faster than live and many extra important reasons are here http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the event to listen for (in this case `click`) to the `live` method.

```
$("#somediv").live("click", function () {
    console.log("you clicked it");
});
```

Also, as the other answerer said, you should use `on` as opposed to `live`, here is an article that explains why: http://bitovi.com/blog/2011/04/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have specified the type of event. It should be `'click'`, and if my extremely limited knowledge of jQuery syntax is correct, it should be the first parameter before your callback.

To be on the safe side, I like to have any link that is intended to be handled by JavaScript have `href="javascript:void(null);"`. That way, even if the event handler fails to cancel the event, nothing will happen anyway. It's also less confusing for the users to see a JavaScript link in their status bar when you hover over it, than a link to Google.